# Reason for large barrier of hydrogenation of ATP

Tags: biochemistry, hydrolysis

Why does hydrogenation of ATP have high barrier (mostly doesn't happen spontaneous in typical biological conditions) compared to hydrogenation of OH- (does happen spontaneously). Both contain Oxygen atom with one covalent bond and -1 formal charge. One would naively expect the two reaction have similar properties.

Is the reaction product of hydrolysis of ATP somehow high in energy, while water is low in energy? Does the phosphates somehow "magically" make the reaction barrier higher?

Comment: Sorry. English is not my first language. I'm a physics grad student who is not familiar with nomenclature of chemistry. I meant to say hydrogenation or whatever adding a hydrogen in this context is called.

Comment: It's not the wrong word, definitely not hydrogenation. You compare hydrolysis of ATP with what really? Protonation of hydroxide anion? It's completely different thing!

Comment: "You compare hydrolysis of ATP with what really? Protonation of hydroxide anion?" I'm comparing protonation of ATP with protonation of hydroxide anion. I saw figures of ATP whose phosphates carry oxygen anion (I heard this charge repulsion is why ATP has higher energy than ADP). I saw a post talking about how the protonation of APT's oxygen anion has large barrier. I don't understand why, so I asked this question here. BTW, I sense some annoyance/agitation from you. You seem to be a generous person who's willing to share your knowledge to others. Having a positive attitude makes things better.

Comment: Adding a proton to ATP is no different than adding it to hydroxide anion. ATP is way less basic, but there isn't any high barrier. Both get protonated and than lose proton in a matter of nanoseconds. So... I still don't get what you're talking about.

Comment: Couldn't you just write the reactions?

Comment: Okay. I think I know where my confusion is. I was confused why is ATP often drawn with phosphates connecting negative anions ( P-O- ) instead of hydroxial group (P-OH). When I googled this, I saw the answer to "Why is ATP stable? Why doesn't it get hydrolyzed easily in the cell?", is that it has high barrier. I thought it means that the reaction from PO- + H+ -> P-OH has high barrier... but I now know that hydrolysis of ATP doesn't mean the reaction PO- + H+ -> P-OH.

Comment: The later reaction, like you said, happens all the time at nanosecond scale. It is less basic due to resonance between O=P-O and O-P=O, similar to Carboxylate ion.

Comment: Well, I did say it's a different thing. knowing right jargon is very important in making useful answer.